# Sending data to Zeitgeist via MQ and/or JMS?

Tags: jms, gnome, mq, zeitgeist

I have a Java application that I want to send data to the Gnome (Activity) Journal. To keep code loosely coupled I'd like to use a MQ between my Java app and the Zeitgeist API (this allows to swap out the destination without changing my app).

So I'm looking for a way to add data to Zeitgeist from a message queue. Is there sample code somewhere?

Comment: This sounds like pointless double-indirection. Dbus is already a messaging service; you can also swap out the zeitgeist implementation with Dbus, if you had another zeitgeist implementation.

Comment: @Robin Green: on the first look you are right. however.. Just imagine the Java app including the MQ is cross platform. On Linux it needs to write to dbus. Elsewhere to a custom mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [DBUS API documentation](http://zeitgeist-project.com/docs/0.8.2/).

Comment: I am aware of that documentation. It doesn't exactly outline what is a good strategy to get stuff from an MQ into the DBUS. Pull/Push and last time I checked -> no code sample for that.